# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Sheet index (26) is out of range (0..2)

Tags: java, excel, selenium-webdriver, apache-poi

When i am trying to write data into excel sheet, i am getting above Exception. Please refer the solution for my problem.

**Please find my code below:**

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import java.io.IOException;

import java.util.List;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;

import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;

public class CityBusRoutes {

    static String routeName;

    static String routeList;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",
                "D://Selenium//Selenium Drivers//chromedriver_win32//chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

        driver.get("http://www.onefivenine.com/busRoute.dont?method=findBusRoute");

        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        Select ddl1 = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("cityId")));

        List<WebElement> elementCount = ddl1.getOptions();

        int citiesCount = elementCount.size();

        for (int i = 1; i <= citiesCount; i++) {

            ddl1.selectByIndex(i);

            Select ddl2 = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("routeId")));

            List<WebElement> element = ddl2.getOptions();

            int routesCount = element.size();

            for (int j = 1; j <= routesCount; j++) {

                ddl2.selectByIndex(j);

                routeName = driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[2]/div[2]/table[2]")).getText();

                routeList = driver
                        .findElement(By.xpath("html/body/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[2]/div[2]/table[3]/tbody/tr/td[1]"))
                        .getText();

                FileInputStream input = new FileInputStream("D:\\Citybus-Routes-List.xlsx");

                XSSFWorkbook wBook = new XSSFWorkbook(input);

                XSSFSheet sh = wBook.getSheetAt(citiesCount);

                int rowCount = sh.getLastRowNum() - sh.getFirstRowNum();

                Row newRow = sh.createRow(rowCount + 1);

                newRow.createCell(0).setCellValue(routeName);

                newRow.createCell(1).setCellValue(routeList);

                input.close();

                FileOutputStream output = new FileOutputStream("D:\\Citybus-Routes-List.xlsx");

                wBook.write(output);

                wBook.close();

                output.close();

            }

            driver.quit();
        }

    }
}
```

**Below is my StackTrace:**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Sheet index (26) is out of range (0..3)
        at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.validateSheetIndex(XSSFWorkbook.java:1236)
        at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.getSheetAt(XSSFWorkbook.java:991)
        at CityBusRoutes.main(CityBusRoutes.java:86)
```

**After completion of one j loop iteration, showing below error**:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.StaleElementReferenceException: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document
  (Session info: chrome=60.0.3112.90)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.29.461591 (62ebf098771772160f391d75e589dc567915b233),platform=Windows NT 6.1.7600 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 30 milliseconds
For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/stale_element_reference.html
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are trying to get sheet that has not been created.
Try to replace

```
XSSFSheet sh = wBook.getSheetAt(citiesCount);
```

with

```
XSSFSheet sh = wBook.createSheet(String.valueOf(i)); //change sheet name if needed
```

Comment: Thanq @Alex for your reply,  Previous problem was solved now i am getting another error i.e., java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The workbook already contains a sheet of this name